# rendering compressed files to angular2 app locally

Tags: angular, webpack, compression, rendering

Due to huge size of bundle.js files in the angular2 app, I have configured `compression-webpack-plugin` in the webpack to compress the files and the compressed files `.js.gz` are generated as expected in the static dist folder. I would want to serve the `.js.gz` files to the browser locally first (and development environment and other environments as well) when the application is requested by the browser. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Which server are you using to serve your local static dist folder?

This is its job to manipulate your .js.gz files.

With node lite-server, you can add these options:

```
// lite-server-config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  server : {
    middleware : { 1 : require('compression')() }
    ...
  }
};
```

For the webpack-dev-server, you can try to run with the 'compress' option:

```
$> webpack-dev-server --compress
```

source : http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#webpack-dev-server-cli

Comment: I use @angular/cli and webpack; The current version of '@angular/cli' does not serve files from dist folder. To compress the bundles, I did an eject of webpack.config.js and added the plugin for compression there. Can you tell me where I can find the information on server locally, is it on @angular/cli?

Comment: I use `ng serve` to start the server. Doc says `When running ng serve, the compiled output is served from memory, not from disk. This means that the application being served is not located on disk in the dist folder. ` How can I make the app to serve from dist folder?